# Logging last Bash command to file from script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I write lots of small scripts to manipulate files on a Bash-based server. I would like to have a mechanism by which to log which commands created which files in a given directory. However, I don't just want to capture *every* input command, all the time.

**Approach 1**: a wrapper script that uses a Bash builtin (a la `history` or `fc -ln -1`) to grab the last command and write it to a log file. I have not been able to figure out any way to do this, as the shell builtin commands do not appear to be recognized outside of the interactive shell.

**Approach 2**: a wrapper script that pulls from `~/.bash_history` to get the last command. This, however, requires setting up the Bash shell to flush every command to history immediately (as per [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/162643/277995)) and seems also to require that the history be allowed to grow inexorably. If this is the only way, so be it, but it would be great to avoid having to edit the `~/.bashrc` file on every system where this might be implemented.

**Approach 3**: use [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html). My problem with this is that it requires multiple commands to start and stop the logging, and because it launches its own shell it is not callable from within another script (or at least, doing so complicates things significantly).

I am trying to figure out an implementation that's of the form `log_this.script other_script other_arg1 other_arg2 > file`, where everything after the first argument is logged. The emphasis here is on efficiency and minimizing syntax overhead.

EDIT: [iLoveTux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2723675/ilovetux) and I both came up with similar solutions. For those interested, my own implementation follows. It is somewhat more constrained in its functionality than the accepted answer, but it also auto-updates any existing logfile entries with changes (though not deletions).

Sample usage:

```
$ cmdlog.py "python3 test_script.py > test_file.txt"
```

creates a log file in the parent directory of the output file with the following:

```
2015-10-12@10:47:09 test_file.txt   "python3 test_script.py > test_file.txt"
```

Additional file changes are added to the log;

```
$ cmdlog.py "python3 test_script.py > test_file_2.txt"
```

the log now contains

```
2015-10-12@10:47:09 test_file.txt   "python3 test_script.py > test_file.txt"
2015-10-12@10:47:44 test_file_2.txt "python3 test_script.py > test_file_2.txt"
```

Running on the original file name again changes the file order in the log, based on modification time of the files:

```
$ cmdlog.py "python3 test_script.py > test_file.txt"
```

produces

```
2015-10-12@10:47:44 test_file_2.txt "python3 test_script.py > test_file_2.txt"
2015-10-12@10:48:01 test_file.txt   "python3 test_script.py > test_file.txt"
```

Full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
A wrapper script that will write the command-line
args associated with any files generated to a log
file in the directory where the files were made.

'''
import sys
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import subprocess
import time
from datetime import datetime

def listFiles(mypath):
    """
    Return relative paths of all files in mypath

    """
    return [join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if
            isfile(join(mypath, f))]

def read_log(log_file):
    """
    Reads a file history log and returns a dictionary
    of {filename: command} entries.

    Expects tab-separated lines of [time, filename, command]

    """
    entries = {}
    with open(log_file) as log:
        for l in log:
            l = l.strip()
            mod, name, cmd = l.split("\t")
            # cmd = cmd.lstrip("\"").rstrip("\"")
            entries[name] = [cmd, mod]
    return entries

def time_sort(t, fmt):
    """
    Turn a strftime-formatted string into a tuple
    of time info

    """
    parsed = datetime.strptime(t, fmt)
    return parsed

ARGS = sys.argv[1]
ARG_LIST = ARGS.split()

# Guess where logfile should be put
if (">" or ">>") in ARG_LIST:
    # Get position after redirect in arg list
    redirect_index = max(ARG_LIST.index(e) for e in ARG_LIST if e in ">>")
    output = ARG_LIST[redirect_index + 1]
    output = os.path.abspath(output)
    out_dir = os.path.dirname(output)
elif ("cp" or "mv") in ARG_LIST:
    output = ARG_LIST[-1]
    out_dir = os.path.dirname(output)
else:
     out_dir = os.getcwd()

# Set logfile location within the inferred output directory
LOGFILE = out_dir + "/cmdlog_history.log"

# Get file list state prior to running
all_files = listFiles(out_dir)
pre_stats = [os.path.getmtime(f) for f in all_files]

# Run the desired external commands
subprocess.call(ARGS, shell=True)

# Get done time of external commands
TIME_FMT = "%Y-%m-%d@%H:%M:%S"
log_time = time.strftime(TIME_FMT)

# Get existing entries from logfile, if present
if LOGFILE in all_files:
    logged = read_log(LOGFILE)
else:
    logged = {}

# Get file list state after run is complete
post_stats = [os.path.getmtime(f) for f in all_files]
post_files = listFiles(out_dir)

# Find files whose states have changed since the external command
changed = [e[0] for e in zip(all_files, pre_stats, post_stats) if e[1] != e[2]]
new = [e for e in post_files if e not in all_files]
all_modded = list(set(changed + new))

if not all_modded:  # exit early, no need to log
    sys.exit(0)

# Replace files that have changed, add those that are new
for f in all_modded:
    name = os.path.basename(f)
    logged[name] = [ARGS, log_time]

# Write changed files to logfile
with open(LOGFILE, 'w') as log:
    for name, info in sorted(logged.items(), key=lambda x: time_sort(x[1][1], TIME_FMT)):
        cmd, mod_time = info
        if not cmd.startswith("\""):
            cmd = "\"{}\"".format(cmd)
        log.write("\t".join([mod_time, name, cmd]) + "\n")

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried `nohup`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think you may have misunderstood my goal.

Comment: That's why I made it a comment. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `nohup` will log stdout and stderr to a file, but I want to capture the entirety of the command line *input*, including redirects, pipes, etc. Basically, I need exactly what the Bash builtin `fc -ln -1` produces, but automated.

Comment: In an interactive shell? If you're doing this programmatically, don't you have the command already?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch take this as an example: I'm going to run the command `script1 -option1 -option2 file2 file5 file8 > file10`. After the fact, I'd like to have a record of the exact command that produced `file10` in that directory. I'm looking for a quick way to automate the record-keeping on a selective basis, e.g. "okay, I'm about to create an important file, let me add a command to log its creation to a logfile in the directory"

Comment: How did you determine the command you're about to run? That's where you could log it... I'm not aware of any built-in non-interactive (ruling out fc and bash_history in general) method to log commands.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not sure I understand your point about how I determined the commands to run, but there are of course many manual ways I could go about logging this information. I don't see why `bash_history` need necessarily be ruled out, assuming there's a way to keep it from growing unwieldy in the process. I am just wondering whether anyone knows of a better, faster way, hence the question.

Comment: What about a script that evaluates the rest of the command line and uses the very last argument as the file to redirect results to ?
`logCommand script1 -option1 -option2 file2 file5 file8 file10`

Comment: @Pawamoy a nice idea, but it doesn't seem very general because it would require gymnastics to account for multiple redirects/pipes/other logging, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you don't mention Python in your question, but it is tagged Python, so I figured I would see what I could do. I came up with this script:

```
import sys
from os.path import expanduser, join
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def issue_command(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    return process.communicate()

home = expanduser("~")
log_file = join(home, "command_log")

command = sys.argv[1:]
with open(log_file, "a") as fout:
    fout.write("{}\n".format(" ".join(command)))

out, err = issue_command(command)
```

which you can call like (if you name it log_this and make it executable):

```
$ log_this echo hello world
```

and it will put "echo hello world" in a file `~/command_log`, note though that if you want to use pipes or redirection you have to quote your command (this may be a real downfall for your use case or it may not be, but I haven't figured out how to do this just yet without the quotes) like this:

```
$ log_this "echo hello world | grep h >> /tmp/hello_world"
```

but since it's not perfect, I thought I would add a little something extra.

The following script allows you to specify a different file to log your commands to as well as record the execution time of the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import argparse
from os.path import expanduser, join
from time import time


def issue_command(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    return process.communicate()

home = expanduser("~")
default_file = join(home, "command_log")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", type=argparse.FileType("a"), default=default_file)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--profile", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("command", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.profile:
    start = time()
    out, err = issue_command(args.command)
    runtime = time() - start
    entry = "{}\t{}\n".format(" ".join(args.command), runtime)
    args.file.write(entry)
else:
    out, err = issue_command(args.command)
    entry = "{}\n".format(" ".join(args.command))
    args.file.write(entry)

args.file.close()
```

You would use this the same way as the other script, but if you wanted to specify a different file to log to just pass `-f <FILENAME>` before your actual command and your log will go there, and if you wanted to record the execution time just provide the `-p` (for profile) before your actual command like so:

```
$ log_this -p -f ~/new_log "echo hello world | grep h >> /tmp/hello_world"
```

I will try to make this better, but if you can think of anything else this could do for you, I am making a [github project](https://github.com/iLoveTux/log_this/tree/develop) for this where you can submit bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: Nice. I ended up writing something very similar last night, as it happens. Yours is a little more general, but mine is a little more tailored to my workflow. As far as I can tell, quote-wrapping the external arguments (my approach too) is the most efficient way to do this. Still a little awkward for my taste, but apparently it's not a very common use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tee` command, which stores its standard input to a file *and* outputs it on standard output. Pipe the command line into `tee`, and pipe `tee`'s output into a new invocation of your shell:

```
echo '<command line to be logged and executed>' | \
    tee --append /path/to/your/logfile | \
    $SHELL
```

i.e., for your example of `other_script other_arg1 other_arg2 > file`,

```
echo 'other_script other_arg1 other_arg2 > file' | \
    tee --append /tmp/mylog.log | \
    $SHELL
```

If your command line needs single quotes, they need to be escaped properly.

Comment: This is nice, but I'm trying to find something that's much more streamlined (i.e. doesn't require worry about escaping characters, or adding multiple additional arguments). Using `script` is similarly effective but cumbersome.